# How to work with a range of n-grams on Facebook FastText?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, fasttext

I am trying to train a text classifier with [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/). It has a bunch of [options](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/options.html) along with a facility to [train](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#word-n-grams) from the command line. One of the options is `wordNgrams`.

In my particular dataset, I discovered that many irrelevant queries are being classified with high confidence because they share similar tokens. So, my plan was to ignore the `unigram` tokens and start from `bigram`. Now I go from 1st gram up to 5th gram by setting `wordNgrams = 5`, but my plan is to go from 2nd gram to 5th gram. But it seems to be that `FastText` doesn't support this. Is there any way to achieve this, this is required to minimize these `False Positives`.

Comment: Fyi increasing ngram size can cause overfitting, make sure the training set is large enough.

Comment: @Erwan the `wordNgrams = 5` in this case is found via gridsearch.

Comment: What do you mean by "go from 2nd gram to 5th gram"? (How is that any different than the `wordNgrams=5` parameter you've already reported trying?) Are you using FastText's `-supervised` mode, or using FastText features for some other classifier?

Comment: @gojomo in https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#word-n-grams it is said that "... we can improve the performance of a model by using word bigrams, instead of just unigram". It is said when `wordNgrams 2` is used. This means that it starts from `wordNgrams 1` and goes up to `wordNgrams 2`. So, if we set `5` then it will take each of the `1` to `5` th grams. But I am trying to skip the `unigrams` and just go from `2-gram` up to `5-gram`. I am using FastText `-supervised` and on top of that, I wrote a `scikit-learn` wrapper in order to do the grid-search-cv hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: @gojomo something like `ngram_range` in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, even though Facebook's `fasttext` lets users set a range for character-n-grams (subword information), using `-minn` & `-maxn`, it only offers a single `-wordNgrams` parameter setting the maximum length of word-multigrams.

However, it is also the case that the `-supervised` mode combines all the given tokens in an order-oblivious way. Thus, you could in your own preprocessing create whatever mix of n-grams (or other token-represented features) you'd like, then pass those to `fasttext` (which it would consider as all unigrams). As long as you apply the same preprocessing in training as in later classification, the effect should be the same.

(You could even use the `sklearn` `CountVectorizer`'s preprocessing.)

Keep in mind the warning from ~Erwan in a comment, though: adding so many distinct features increases the risk of overfitting, which could show up as your stated problem  "many irrelevant queries are being classified with high confidence because they share similar tokens". (The model, made large by the inclusion of so many n-grams, has memorized idiosyncratic minutia from the training-data. That then leads it astray applying non-generalizable inferences to out-of-training data.)

Comment: Basically, this is why I want to take **only** higher-gram skipping the lower-gram tokens. As the higher-gram contains **more context-specific** information and is **less likely to be found in irrelevant cases**. My current target is to increase the precision, recall is secondary, as a wrong prediction may create a catastrophe in my domain.